# Using each line of awk output as grep pattern

Tags: awk, grep

I want to find every line of a file that contains any of the strings held in a column of a different file.

I have tried
`grep "$(awk '{ print $1 }' file1.txt)" file2.txt`
but that just outputs file2.txt in its entirety.

I know I've done this before with a pattern I found on this site, but I can't find that question anymore.

Comment: The command in the OP does what it is supposed to. 

My problem was that file1 had a blank line which was sending the pattern "" to grep, causing it to find every line in file2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see in the OP's comment that maybe the question is no longer a question.  However, the following slight modification will handle the blank line situation.  Just add a check to make sure the line has at least one field:

```
grep "$(awk '{if (NF > 0) print $1}' file1)" file2
```

And if the file with the patterns is simply a set of patterns per line, then a much simpler version of it is:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

That causes grep to use the lines in file1 as the patterns.

Answer (score 2):

THere is no need to use `grep` when you have `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR&&NF{a[$0];next}($1 in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

$(awk '{ print $1 }' file1.txt) | grep text > file.txt