# Pipe grep results to awk, get field, pipe field list as pattern to grep in same file

Tags: awk, grep

I'm having a hard time figuring out a one-liner to search for a pattern in a file, get a field from the matching lines, and search the same file again with that field as a pattern, to get a different field. You could say the data looks like this:

```
CONNECT=desired_output CONNECTION=pattern2  
SEARCH=pattern1 CONNECTION=pattern2
```

So far I've tried these unholy messes to no avail:

```
zgrep -i pattern1 file | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -I % zgrep % file | zgrep pattern2
zgrep -i pattern1 file | awk '{print $8}' | zgrep -f - file
```

If I leave off the last grep, it gives results (which would need another grep and awk to get the desired output field). If I include the last grep, it never comes back with output.

Similar questions seem to point to awk being able to do this whole concept, but I can't decipher the examples given to adjust to my use case.

- [Using each line of awk output as grep pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809523/using-each-line-of-awk-output-as-grep-pattern/5826329#5826329)
- [How to run grep inside awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080098/how-to-run-grep-inside-awk/20080263#20080263)

Comment: Could you add the expected output (and what you get instead)? It's hard to see what exactly you're trying to get.

Comment: Updated with expected versus actual output. Basically the file has many lines that each have the same "CONNECTION" key. I'm searching by a field on one of the lines, and I'd like to get a field on another line, where both lines have the same key.

Comment: I meant that exact (testable) output, not a description of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this, untested since you didn't provide testable input/output:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if ( /constant_regexp1/ ) {
        dynamic_regexp2 = $8
    }
    next
}
$0 ~ dynamic_regexp2
' file file
```

Never use the word "pattern" btw as it's ambiguous, always use "string" or "regexp", whichever it is you mean.